# Merging several entities (polyline) into single entity using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a vector layer containing road axes (directions) which are each divided into segments. I would like to merge its segments into a single polylines per axis (route) and I am looking for a QGIS tool which allows it to be done with several segments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `virtual layer` to merge the segments, using the `st_union` operator on groups of segments having the same `roadid`.

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query. Replace the layer name for yours and feel free to add any field you want in the `select`

```sql
select roadid, st_union(geometry) as geometry
from roads
group by roadid
```

Here is the source segments and the query
[image]

and the result

[image]